# selenium script written in _init_ function not executing

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-selenium

I am trying to integrate selenium with scrapy to render javascript from a website. I have put the selenium automation code in a constructor, it performs a button click, and then the parse function scrapes the data from the page. But follwing errors are appearing in the terminal window.
code :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which

class test_2(scrapy.Spider):
    name='test_2'
    #allowed_domains=[]
    start_urls=[
        'https://www.jackjones.in/st-search?q=shoes'
        ]
    
    def _init_(self):
        print("test-1")
        chrome_options=Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        
        driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver")
        driver.set_window(1920,1080)
        driver.get("https://www.jackjones.in/st-search?q=shoes")
        tab=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("st-single-product")
        tab[4].click()

        self.html=driver.page_source
        print("test-2")
        driver.close()
    
    def parse(self, response):
        print("test-3")
        resp=Selector(text=self.html)
        yield{
            'title':resp.xpath("//h1/text()").get()
        }
```

It appears that compiler does not execute the **init** function before going to parse function, because neither of the print statements are getting executed but the print statement in parse function is present in the output.

How to fix this?

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\Vasu\summer\scrapy_selenium> scrapy crawl test_2
2022-07-01 13:18:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: scrapy_selenium)
2022-07-01 13:18:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.0.0, libxml2 2.9.14, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, 
w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.4.0, Python 3.8.13 (default, Mar 28 2022, 06:59:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 
22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1p  21 Jun 2022), cryptography 37.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
2022-07-01 13:18:30 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'scrapy_selenium',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapy_selenium.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapy_selenium.spiders']}
2022-07-01 13:18:30 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-07-01 13:18:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 168b57499cd07735
2022-07-01 13:18:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-07-01 13:18:31 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-07-01 13:18:31 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-07-01 13:18:31 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-07-01 13:18:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-07-01 13:18:31 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-07-01 13:18:31 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-07-01 13:18:31 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 1385261511056 on C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-07-01 13:18:31 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 1385261511056 acquired on C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock        
2022-07-01 13:18:32 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 1385261511056 on C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-07-01 13:18:32 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 1385261511056 released on C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock        
2022-07-01 13:18:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.jackjones.in/st-search?q=shoes> (referer: None)
test-3
2022-07-01 13:18:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.jackjones.in/st-search?q=shoes> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 132, in iter_errback    
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 354, in __next__       
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 354, in __next__       
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 66, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 66, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 342, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 66, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 40, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 66, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\anaconda3\envs\sca_sel\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 66, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Vasu\summer\scrapy_selenium\scrapy_selenium\spiders\test_2.py", line 31, in parse
    resp=Selector(text=self.html)
AttributeError: 'test_2' object has no attribute 'html'
2022-07-01 13:18:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-07-01 13:18:32 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 237,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 20430,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.613799,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 1, 7, 48, 32, 202155),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 87151,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 1, 7, 48, 31, 588356)}
2022-07-01 13:18:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `__init__`, not `_init_` (note the double underscores).

Secondly, there is no `h1` on the page. Try this instead:

```
    yield {
        'title':resp.xpath("//title/text()").get()
    }
```